# Qt Creator 100% CPU during code edit

Tags: qt, boost, include, qt-creator, point-cloud-library

I have Qt Creator project. It uses `boost` and `Point Cloud library`. When I edit file that contains includes from these libraries, Qt Creator hangs about 30 seconds after each code channge (line added, variable type changed etc.). TaskManager shows 100% CPU on my two-core procesor.

Please note: it is not during parsing or indexing, i.e. no green progress bar appears.

Qt Creator is 2.8.0.

Comment: The creator gets stuck, the mocking crashes... it's kind of normal for Qt :)

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this issue? I'm experiencing it too and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found is to disable `boost` and `Eigen` header parsing. To do it

1. Exclude them from `HEADERS` section of `.pro` file
2. Add these lines:

   `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /I ../3rdparty/eigen  /I ../3rdparty/boost /DCOMPILE_TIME`

   Now Qt Creator will show you `Unknow file` warning, but compilation will be OK.