# Qt Creator 100% CPU and crash during code edit

Tags: c++, qt, boost

The problem: when I edit code file, Qt Creator get stuck and crashes with 100 CPU usage.

Interesting: 
with Boost 1.54 - nothing happends -> all okay,
with Boost 1.60 -> several seconds freeze and 100 CPU usage,
with Boost 1.60 and make addition `-j6` -> crash.

How have I change Boost version?

Simply copy and paste new boost version to my `/usr/include`. Bad way, maybe.
But even on my laptop with Boost like library usage this problem also exist.

Not working:
[Qt Creator 100% CPU during code edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078732/qt-creator-100-cpu-during-code-edit),
[Qt creator high cpu usage in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274409/qt-creator-high-cpu-usage-in-editor)

Qt Creator version - 3.5.1
Boost version - 1.60(problem), 1.54(okay)

Any suggestions?

EDIT: back to boost 1.54 -> Qt Creator still crashes.

Comment: So, for EDIT Problem (qt creator + boost 1.54) solution: uninstall orca screen reader(thanks to last update for ubuntu 14.04) and reinstall lib-boost1.54 for sure.

Comment: Now, with boost 1.60 and Qt Creator 3.6(just update) without orca all work well.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove Orca.

No QMAKE flags required.
Changing Qt Creator options has no effect.